# Can I make the contents of a page fade-in and fade-out in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a content page that displays words. I get the words from the database, populate a view model which in turn changes label text through bindings and then this code makes the new words visible:

```
phrasesPageStackLayout.IsVisible = true;
```

After a few seconds this makes the words disappear:

```
phrasesPageStackLayout.IsVisible = false;
```

I get a new word and the process starts again.

In Xamarin.Forms is it possibly for me to make the words fade into view and fade out of view. For example over a period of 3 seconds?

Comment: Animations are supported out of the box by XF. Check the official guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to use [animation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/) to achieve your effect. For example use `MyTextLabel.FadeTo(0, 3000);` to achieve your **FadeOut** effect. If you want your label to FadeIn first and then FadeOut try this:

```
await MyTextLabel.FadeTo(1, 1500);
await MyTextLabel.FadeTo(0, 1500);
```

Comment: Is there a way that I could make this apply to all of the labels on my stack layout at the same time?

Comment: @Alan2 You can make your layout call this method like:"MyStacklayout.FadeTo(0, 1500)"

Answer (score 2):

I prefer use reusable approaches, then I've created an extension method to handle with this kind of need:

```
public static class VisualElementExtensions
{
    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task FadeOut(this VisualElement element, uint duration = 400, Easing easing = null)
    {
        await element.FadeTo(0, duration, easing);
        element.IsVisible = false;
    }

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task FadeIn(this VisualElement element, uint duration = 400, Easing easing = null)
    {
        await element.FadeTo(1, duration, easing);
        element.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

You can use it in any VisualElement you wish (Button, Label, Layouts and so on) like this:

```
phrasesPageStackLayout.FadeOut (); /* I guess 1.5 seconds is too much time to this kind of purpose, but you can do `phrasesPageStackLayout.FadeOut (3000)` if you need. */ 
// Or 
phrasesPageStackLayout.FadeIn (500, Easing.CubicOut)
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, would this fade in all of the text that's in labels that are on the phrasesPageStackLayout at the same time?

Comment: Yes @Alan2, the effect should be applied on the Layout and all it's children

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to have a look at Xamanimation - you'll get standard animations right out of the box:
https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/Xamanimation